# WooCommerce -> wc_enqueue_js not working

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a plugin that was using a deprecated function **add_inline_js**.

I've changed it for **wc_enqueue_js** but it's not working. What I'm doing wrong?

```
$woocommerce->wc_enqueue_js(
file_get_contents( WOO_CK_PATH . 'panel.js' )
);
```

Fatal error: Call to undefined method WooCommerce::wc_enqueue_js()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wc_enqueue_js` is not `method` of `$woocommerce` object.

Just call the function.

```
wc_enqueue_js( file_get_contents( WOO_CK_PATH . 'panel.js' ) );
```